# How to use Hebrew font in Kivy?

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

I try to use Hebrew font in kivy app and after explore i use  LabelBase.register and change my reading of the kv file with encoding='utf-8' but still get error with the line: font_name.
my main.py:

```
# main.py

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase
LabelBase.register(name="Arial", fn_regular="Arial.ttf")

class exist_form_window(Screen):
    project_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    manage_name = ObjectProperty(None)

    def create(self):
        if (self.project_name.text):
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "main"
        else:
            invalidLogin()  

    def reset(self):
        self.project_name.text =""
        self.manage_name.text = ""



class new_form_window(Screen):
    project_name = ObjectProperty(None)
    manage_name = ObjectProperty(None)

    def create(self):
        if (self.project_name.text):
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "main"
        else:
            invalidLogin()  

    def reset(self):
        self.project_name.text =""
        self.manage_name.text = ""

class MainWindow(Screen):
    def new_form(self):
        sm.current = "new_form"
    def exist_form(self):
        sm.current = "exist_form"

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

def invalidLogin():
    pop = Popup(title='שגיאה',
                  content=Label(text='חלק מהערכים חסרים'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()

with open("roniapp.kv", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    Builder.load_string(f.read())

sm = WindowManager()

screens = [MainWindow(name="main"),new_form_window(name="new_form"),exist_form_window(name="exist_form")]

for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "main"


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

My roniapp.kv file:

```
<MainWindow>:
name: "main"

FloatLayout:
    Label:
    font_name: 'Arial'  
        text:"Asad"
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
        size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.2, "y": 0.3}
        size_hint:0.6,0.2
        text: "aaa"
        on_release:
            root.new_form()
            root.manager.transition.direction = "down"

    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.2, "y": 0.1}
        size_hint:0.6,0.2
        text: "aaa"
        on_release:
            root.exist_form()
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"



<new_form_window>:
name: "new_form"

project_name: project_name
manage_name: manage_name

FloatLayout:

    Label:
        text:"aaa"
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
        size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

    TextInput:
        id: project_name
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        multiline: False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "top":0.9}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

    Label:
        text:"aaa"
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.7}
        size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

    TextInput:
        id: manage_name
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        multiline: False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.45, "top":0.7}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        text: "aaa"
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            root.create()

<exist_form_window>:
name: "exist_form"

project_name: project_name
manage_name: manage_name

FloatLayout:

    Label:
        text:"aaa"
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
        size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

    TextInput:
        id: project_name
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        multiline: False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "top":0.9}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

    Label:
        text:"aaa"
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.7}
        size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

    TextInput:
        id: manage_name
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        multiline: False
        pos_hint: {"x": 0.45, "top":0.7}
        size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

    Button:
        pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
        size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
        font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
        text: "aaa"
        on_release:
            root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
            root.create()
```

And get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\adi\Anaconda3\envs\project_2\lib\site-packages\kivy\lang\parser.py", line 584, in 
parse_level
 'Invalid data after declaration')

ParserException: Parser: File "<inline>", line 6:
...
      4:    FloatLayout:
      5:        Label:
>>    6:        font_name: 'Arial'  
      7:            text:"Asad"
      8:            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
...
Invalid data after declaration
```

If it's because i save the kv file with notepad i try with different apps and still get this error.

thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The kivy Parser is throwing an error because the code in your .kv file is not formed correctly. Your **indentation** needs to be fixed. I managed to run your app on my machine by keeping your python code unchanged and replacing your .kv file with the following:

```
<MainWindow>:
    name: "main"
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            font_name: 'Arial'  
            text:"Asad"
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2, "y": 0.3}
            size_hint:0.6,0.2
            text: "aaa"
            on_release:
                root.new_form()
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2, "y": 0.1}
            size_hint:0.6,0.2
            text: "aaa"
            on_release:
                root.exist_form()
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"



<new_form_window>:
    name: "new_form"
    project_name: project_name
    manage_name: manage_name
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"aaa"
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

        TextInput:
            id: project_name
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "top":0.9}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

        Label:
            text:"aaa"
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.7}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

        TextInput:
            id: manage_name
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.45, "top":0.7}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            text: "aaa"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.create()

<exist_form_window>:
    name: "exist_form"
    project_name: project_name
    manage_name: manage_name
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            text:"aaa"
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

        TextInput:
            id: project_name
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.45 , "top":0.9}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

        Label:
            text:"aaa"
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.7}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

        TextInput:
            id: manage_name
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.45, "top":0.7}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.15

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.2,"y":0.05}
            size_hint: 0.6, 0.2
            font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            text: "aaa"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.create()
```

And it works:

[image: Ta-da!]